# mvc redirect after delay

Tags: model-view-controller, redirect, delay

I'm recently new in MVC technology and i'm with a difficult

I have a UI to create a user, and when i submit the content and all content is valid i  pass a message into Viewdata["INFO"] and return a View called Info with Viewdata Informing than the user was sucefully created.

But in this moment i want to Regist a some script than, after a one delay specified the client redirects automatically to the base page "Users".

Any ideas to get the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Meta Refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#Refresh_Meta_tag_and_HTTP_refresh_header) - See if this answers your question.  You can specify a duration and location.  Works on any browser as well!

Answer (score 1):

You could just add a [META REFRESH](http://webdesign.about.com/od/metataglibraries/a/aa080300a.htm) tag to the page dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it is a bit late in comparison to the time this post was initially done, but just to make sure somebody finds this post beneficial.

Here is a JavaScript function that will redirect to the mentioned URL after five seconds:

```
  setTimeout(function() {
   window.location.href = "http://YourRespectiveUserBaseUrl/;" 
  }, 5000);
```